# Cookie randomly expiring on Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, cookies, laravel

I'm doing a app with Laravel 4.1, and when the user logs in, I'm registering some cookies:

```
Cookie::queue('adm-chave', $chave, 30);
Cookie::queue('adm-usuario', $usuario->usuario, 30);
Cookie::queue('adm-usuario-id', $usuario->id, 30);
Cookie::queue('adm-usuario-nome', $usuario->nome, 30);
Cookie::queue('adm-usuario-email', $usuario->email, 30);
```

I did a code to renew the expiration time on every page load, like follows:

```
Route::filter('logado', function()
{
  $chave = Cookie::get('adm-chave');
  $usuario = Cookie::get('adm-usuario');
  $id_usuario = Cookie::get('adm-usuario-id');
  $nome = Cookie::get('adm-usuario-nome');
  $email = Cookie::get('adm-usuario-email');

  if(empty($chave) || empty($id_usuario)){
    $resposta = Redirect::to('/');
    $resposta->withCookie(Cookie::forget('adm-chave'));
    $resposta->withCookie(Cookie::forget('adm-usuario'));
    $resposta->withCookie(Cookie::forget('adm-usuario-id'));
    $resposta->withCookie(Cookie::forget('adm-usuario-nome'));
    $resposta->withCookie(Cookie::forget('adm-usuario-email'));

    return $resposta;
  }

  Cookie::queue('adm-usuario', $usuario, 30);
  Cookie::queue('adm-usuario-id', $id_usuario, 30);
  Cookie::queue('adm-usuario-nome', $nome, 30);
  Cookie::queue('adm-usuario-email', $email, 30);
});
```

Even with this renewal, my cookies are expiring randomly and my user being logged out on that if block.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First we add an option to config/app.php as the following (I've set it to 24 hours):

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Files Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes after which old sessions in
| storage will be seen as 'garbage' and cleaned up. Garbage collection may
| occur during session start, depending on the lottery. The default is 24.
|
*/

'files_lifetime' => 24*60,
```

We then create two files. In SessionServiceProvider.php we overwrite the SessionManager register to use our own SessionManager:

```
<?php namespace YourNamespace\Session;

class SessionServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->setupDefaultDriver();

        $this->registerSessionManager();

        $this->registerSessionDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Register the session manager instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerSessionManager()
    {
        $this->app['session.manager'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new SessionManager($app);
        });
    }

}
```

In SessionManager.php we overwrite the getOptions() method to set gc_maxlifetime as well:

```
<?php namespace YourNamespace\Session;

class SessionManager extends \Illuminate\Session\SessionManager {

    /**
     * Get the session options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        $config = $this->app['config']['session'];

        return array(
            'cookie_domain' => $config['domain'], 'cookie_lifetime' => $config['lifetime'] * 60,
            'cookie_path' => $config['path'], 'cookie_httponly' => '1', 'name' => $config['cookie'],
            'gc_divisor' => $config['lottery'][1], 'gc_probability' => $config['lottery'][0],
            'gc_maxlifetime' => $config['files_lifetime'] * 60,
        );
    }

}
```

**This is where the solution is from https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2314**

Comment: Tried to use that approach, but didn't worked...

When I load both files on my providers array at app.php, Laravel throws:
ReflectionException
Class session does not exist

When I do php artisan dump-auto, it also throws:
{"error":{"type":"ReflectionException","message":"Class session does not exist","file":"\/home\/heitor\/public_html\/project\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Container\/Container.php","line":476}}

How do I include these files to the project and how do I call them at app.php?
Which files I have to change to Laravel know and use these custom providers?

Comment: This solution was for 4.0, the Session handling has since been rebuilt from the ground up in 4.1.